# Streamline reverse geocoding in R

Tags: r, dplyr, arcgis

I am using the reverse_geo() function to get the states to which a list of oil wells belong. The problem is that there are 80 thousand wells and the process becomes very slow. So, to speed up the search I would like to get only the subregion since it is the only data I need. How can I do that?

My code is:

```
library(readxl)
info_pozos <- read_excel("C:/Users/Kevin/Downloads/info_pozos.xlsx")


library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidygeocoder)

reverse <- info_pozos %>%
reverse_geocode(lat = coordenaday, long = coordenadax, method = 'arcgis',
address = address_found, full_results = FALSE)

View(reverse)
```

I expect to gain at least a couple of hours of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottleneck here is not the geographic granularity but rather the
API requests to the geocoding service. Some geocoding services
supported by `tidygeocoder` have batch processing capabilities, which
should speed up the process somewhat.

I’d recommend another strategy, though:

1. Acquire shapefiles/geometry of the subregions/divisions.
2. Perform a geographic join of well coordinates and division geometry.

Assuming that the wells are in the US you can use the `tigris` package
to obtain division geometries from the CENSUS Tiger Line service. The `sf`
package can be used to perform a geographic join with `st_join()`.

For the example below, I downloaded [HIFLD](https://hifld-geoplatform.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/geoplatform::oil-and-natural-gas-wells/explore?location=33.968203%2C-107.871381%2C4.00)
data for 1,506,228 oil and gas wells in the US. (That data already contains
a state column. For the sake of the example, we ignore that column.)
It takes ~15 seconds on my machine to perform the `st_join()` for
all wells in the dataset.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tigris)
library(sf)
options(tigris_use_cache = TRUE)

# Obtain subregions/divisions with `tigris::divisions()` 
# and rename NAME column to division, drop other non-geometry columns
us_devisions <-
  divisions() |>
  select(division = NAME)

# https://opendata.arcgis.com/api/v3/datasets/17c5ed5a6bd44dd0a52c616a5b0cacca_0/downloads/data?format=csv&spatialRefId=3857&where=1%3D1
wells <-
  read_csv("Oil__and__Natural__Gas__Wells.csv")

# drop some of the columns and turn well data into an `sf` object
wells_sf <-
  wells |>
  select(ID, NAME, LONGITUDE, LATITUDE) |>
  st_as_sf(coords = c("LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE"),
           crs = st_crs(us_devisions))

# perform geographic join
system.time({
  res <-
    st_join(wells_sf, us_devisions, join = st_within)
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>  15.013   0.336  15.371

res
#> Simple feature collection with 1506238 features and 3 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -160.0238 ymin: 25.88125 xmax: -74.45766 ymax: 71.0696
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD83
#> # A tibble: 1,506,238 × 4
#>    ID         NAME                                       geometry division      
#>  * <chr>      <chr>                                   <POINT [°]> <chr>         
#>  1 W220000001 RRBB NAB PXY RA SU;J L SCALES  (-93.55748 32.06496) West South Ce…
#>  2 W220000002 P SUHH;J B BARR 28             (-93.90817 32.08437) West South Ce…
#>  3 W220000003 HOSS RB SUA;POLAND               (-92.74102 32.651) West South Ce…
#>  4 W220000004 LODWICK LUMBER COMPANY         (-93.47957 32.60635) West South Ce…
#>  5 W220000005 SL 1367                        (-90.17218 29.06883) <NA>          
#>  6 W220000006 THE LOUISIANA FRUIT COMPANY    (-89.36671 29.23455) West South Ce…
#>  7 W220000007 CONTINENTAL SECURITIES         (-93.48068 32.62225) West South Ce…
#>  8 W220000008 LR CIB 32A 8 RA SU;SL 1450     (-90.34038 29.26782) <NA>          
#>  9 W220000009 DL OPERC 2 RA SU;SCHWING L&S E (-91.32461 29.79531) West South Ce…
#> 10 W220000010 HOSS A SUJJ;WOODARD-WALKER L   (-93.14482 32.48034) West South Ce…
#> # ℹ 1,506,228 more rows
```